# Code Igniter active record not working for date in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I ma new to CI.I want to retrieve results based on current date  from the database but due to some reason  my "where" clause is not working and not returning any results.

```
  $date=date('Y-m-d');
  $this->middb->select('clickFrom,datePost,count(*) as total');
 // tried hard coded value but didnt work     
    # $this->middb->where("date(datePost)","2014-09-10");
    $this->middb->where('date(datePost) ="'.$date.'"', null,true);
        $this->middb->where('date(datePost)',$date);
     $this->middb->group_by('clickFrom');
    $query=$this->middb->get('member_daily_click');

   if($query->result())
    {

        print_r($query->result());


    }else{
        die($this->middb->_error_message());

    }        

   die();
```

my "datePost" field is of "DateTime" data type and has got values like '2014-09-10 10:39:30' in the database.I want to compare only dates(not timestamps) in my "where " clause.I am not getting a clue where i am making mistake.

Also, my "   die($this->middb->_error_message());" portion is not displaying any error.I am not sure what is stopping it to display errors.

Any help would be highly appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass third parameter as `FALSE` to prevent from back-ticks added by active record if you leave third parameter so active record will add additional back-ticks to your clause

```
$this->middb->where('date(datePost)',$date,FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks .Sorry it is still not returning anything.My query ["SELECT `clickFrom`, `datePost`, count(*) as total FROM (`member_daily_click`) WHERE date(datePost) = '2014-09-10' GROUP BY `clickFrom`"] works fine on phpmyadmin.Dont know why it is not working.

Comment: @user3489398 this is another question you now you got right query but its not working with your code you need to provide more details  like what is in `middb` how you are using this piece of calling in function or something else

Comment: @user3489398 also remove first `where(...)` function